# I get this error "_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')" from api array call

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, api, rapidapi

I'm working on a app that you can read quran and bible from it and I'm pulling quran surahs and bible books from firebase and write that data to api so that I get all of chapters at once so I have quran and bible apis for it I take care of bible part but with quran json data has array that I want to retrieve all that array and data under that array but I come of to this error while doing it what I'm doing wrong ? if you can help me I really appreciate it thank you very much

my api code:

```
Future getQuran(String surah) async {
    var uri = Uri.https(
      'ajith-holy-bible.p.rapidapi.com',
      '/${surah}',
    );

    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'd88d0a8158mshb8b539da6b34179p137959jsn31258093d5c2',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'al-quran1.p.rapidapi.com'
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response.body);

    List myData = [];
    for (var item in map["verses"]) {
      myData.add(item);
    }

    return myData;
  }
```

this is what api looks like:

- id:114
- surah_name:"AL-NĀS"
- surah_name_ar:"الناس"
- translation:"HUMANS"
- type:"meccan"
- total_verses:6
- description:"The surah that opens with the mention of God as the Lord of Humans and teaches one to seek refuge in Him from the whisperings of Satan and those of evil jinn and people. It takes its name from the word “people” or “mankind” (al-nās) which recurs throughout the surah. This is another surah commonly used as an invocation against evil.The surah is also known as: All People, Humankind, Mankind, People, The Men."
- ▶

  verses:{} 6 keys

  - ▶

    1:{} 4 keys

    - id:1.114
    - content:"قُل أَعوذُ بِرَبِّ النّاسِ"
    - translation_eng:"Say, ‘I seek the protection of the Lord of humans,"
    - transliteration:"qul ʾaʿūdhu bi-rabbi n-nāsi"
  - ▶

    2:{} 4 keys

    - id:2.114
    - content:"مَلِكِ النّاسِ"
    - translation_eng:"Sovereign of humans,"
    - transliteration:"maliki n-nāsi"

this is surahs page:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("quran").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final quran = snapshot.data!.docs[index];

                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Card(
                        borderOnForeground: true,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => SurahReading(
                                              surah: quran["chapter"],
                                              book: quran["surah"],
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Text(quran["surah"]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
```

this surahs reading page:

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: Api().getQuran(widget.surah),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      final quran = snapshot.data;
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: quran.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Row(
                                children: [
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      quran[index]["content"],
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      quran[index]["translation_eng"],
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
```

I did try to get all surahs all ayet from api but I come up to a error and I couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Ok ı figured it out if anyone come up to this error change for to foreach

```
    map["verses"].forEach((key, value) {
  myData.add(value);
});
```